# Analysing long audio files

Tags: audacity, adobe-audition, analysis

I have a 9 hour audio recording.  I need to search through it for occasional short (5 second) low frequency bangs/explosion sounds.  I have audition/audacity. What's the best way to do this, preferably without resorting to command line python scripts?

Comment: How many are you looking for? How far above the noise floor are they? If those answers are 'a few' & 'a lot' I'd just go for the visual scan before even thinking about programming something.

Comment: 8 or 9 bangs. Fairly significantly above the noise floor, but the issue is that they are short.  4-5 second bursts in 9 hours of audio is a lot of haystack and not much needle.

Comment: I'd still be tempted towards a visual scan first - but maybe try Audacity's 'find silence' - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/silence_finder_setting_parameters.html - which might be able to separate wheat from chaff.. (I don't use Audacity or Audition, so idk exactly how you'd run it.)